# Why metaspace didn't get changed in gc log after full gc？

Tags: java, garbage-collection

After full gc, the metaspace didn't change in gc log. But when get metaspace size throw MemoryPoolMXBean, the metaspace size get smaller after full gc. The metaspace size is also getting smaller according to the VisualVm.

So....Why the metaspace didn't change in gc log? For example as below, from 112375K to 112375K.

gc log :

```
2022-08-08T17:09:23.783-0800: 794.694: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2022-08-08T17:09:23.783-0800: 794.694: [ParNew: 715678K->36641K(755008K), 0.0358251 secs] 822252K->143215K(4110464K), 0.0360462 secs] [Times: user=0.10 sys=0.03, real=0.03 secs] 
2022-08-08T17:10:25.985-0800: 856.894: [Full GC (Metadata GC Threshold) 2022-08-08T17:10:25.986-0800: 856.895: [CMS[YG occupancy: 564658 K (755008 K)]2022-08-08T17:10:26.564-0800: 857.473: [weak refs processing, 0.0050842 secs]2022-08-08T17:10:26.569-0800: 857.478: [class unloading, 0.2427045 secs]2022-08-08T17:10:26.811-0800: 857.721: [scrub symbol table, 0.0593686 secs]2022-08-08T17:10:26.871-0800: 857.780: [scrub string table, 0.0021621 secs]: 106574K->86508K(3355456K), 0.9855494 secs] 671232K->651167K(4110464K), [Metaspace: 118866K->118866K(1157120K)], 0.9865607 secs] [Times: user=0.63 sys=0.46, real=0.99 secs] 
2022-08-08T17:10:26.972-0800: 857.881: [Full GC (Last ditch collection) 2022-08-08T17:10:26.972-0800: 857.881: [CMS: 86508K->115396K(3355456K), 0.6005051 secs] 651167K->115396K(4110464K), [Metaspace: 118866K->118866K(1157120K)], 0.6218490 secs] [Times: user=0.43 sys=0.13, real=0.62 secs] 
2022-08-08T17:10:27.594-0800: 858.504: [GC (CMS Initial Mark) [1 CMS-initial-mark: 115396K(3355456K)] 115396K(4110464K), 0.0018789 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2022-08-08T17:10:27.596-0800: 858.506: [CMS-concurrent-mark-start]
2022-08-08T17:10:27.623-0800: 858.533: [CMS-concurrent-mark: 0.027/0.027 secs] [Times: user=0.12 sys=0.02, real=0.03 secs] 
2022-08-08T17:10:27.623-0800: 858.533: [CMS-concurrent-preclean-start]
2022-08-08T17:10:27.630-0800: 858.539: [CMS-concurrent-preclean: 0.006/0.007 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs] 
2022-08-08T17:10:27.631-0800: 858.540: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean-start]
2022-08-08T17:10:29.627-0800: 860.536: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean: 0.112/1.996 secs] [Times: user=2.22 sys=0.39, real=1.99 secs] 
2022-08-08T17:10:29.630-0800: 860.539: [GC (CMS Final Remark) [YG occupancy: 364907 K (755008 K)]2022-08-08T17:10:29.630-0800: 860.539: [Rescan (parallel) , 0.2011922 secs]2022-08-08T17:10:29.831-0800: 860.740: [weak refs processing, 0.0024776 secs]2022-08-08T17:10:29.834-0800: 860.743: [class unloading, 0.0137659 secs]2022-08-08T17:10:29.848-0800: 860.757: [scrub symbol table, 0.0361635 secs]2022-08-08T17:10:29.884-0800: 860.793: [scrub string table, 0.0007877 secs][1 CMS-remark: 115396K(3355456K)] 480303K(4110464K), 0.2546613 secs] [Times: user=0.89 sys=0.07, real=0.25 secs] 
2022-08-08T17:10:29.885-0800: 860.794: [CMS-concurrent-sweep-start]
2022-08-08T17:10:29.911-0800: 860.820: [CMS-concurrent-sweep: 0.026/0.026 secs] [Times: user=0.06 sys=0.01, real=0.03 secs] 
2022-08-08T17:10:29.911-0800: 860.820: [CMS-concurrent-reset-start]
2022-08-08T17:10:29.913-0800: 860.822: [CMS-concurrent-reset: 0.002/0.002 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2022-08-08T17:10:31.244-0800: 862.153: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2022-08-08T17:10:31.244-0800: 862.153: [ParNew: 671168K->25911K(755008K), 0.0418546 secs] 786564K->141308K(4110464K), 0.0422515 secs] [Times: user=0.05 sys=0.01, real=0.04 secs]
```

Another gc log, generated by System.gc() :

```
2022-08-08T16:00:33.622-0800: 920.630: [Full GC (System.gc()) 2022-08-08T16:00:33.631-0800: 920.639: [CMS: 124397K->95303K(3355456K), 4.5840713 secs] 460961K->95303K(4110464K), [Metaspace: 112375K->112375K(1150976K)], 4.7240982 secs] [Times: user=0.44 sys=0.67, real=4.72 secs]
```

Java version :

```
java version "1.8.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)
```

Comment: GC occurs when there's not enough free heap space to allocate a new object, so it attempts to identify unreachable objects to make room for the new one. But metaspace contains class data, not objects. It just doesn't make sense to attempt to clean or compact it, that won't help anyway

Comment: @perterz In my case, there are some class being unloaded. I can see the log by add 'verbose:class' in JVM argument. I also get the metaspace by MemoryPoolMXBean, and it get smaller after full gc.